# Select a second dropdown menu

Tags: c#, webdriver

I can add a second dorpdownmenu to select

> an error says that it is already defined a variable of selectElement

how can I add a 2 select dropdown menu

```
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month")));
selectElement.SelectByText("January");
```

Comment: I am lost. The code looks fine. What's the issue? Provide stacktrace and sounds like a AUT specific issue not `Selenium`

Comment: if I clear "SelectElement selectElement =" and I start this second code of dropdownmenu in "new SelectElement", the error dissapears but the dorpdownmenu is not seleccting "January"

Comment: Then use a different variable.

Comment: What other for a dropdownmeu?

Comment: Do you want to Add Another Dropdown Item? If so Use Dropdown.Items instead of trying to add a new Select Item...There can only be one selected Item, but I am also confused by your statement 2 dropdowns?

Comment: does not work, there is any way to have 2 exact variables in a proyect of selenium with webdriver C#?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean how to work with 2 select objects:

```
SelectElement monthDdList = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month")));
monthDdList.SelectByText("January");

SelectElement daysDdList = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month")));
daysDdList .SelectByText("10");
```

if you mean how to select several items in DDList:

```
SelectElement monthDdList = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Month")));
monthDdList.SelectByText("January");
monthDdList.SelectByText("February");
```